# Improving the performance of STIntersects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, spatial, query-performance

Table `T_PIN` has 300,000 pins and `T_POLYGON` has 36,000 polygons. `T_PIN` has this index:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [T_PIN_COORD] ON [dbo].[T_PIN]
(
[Coord]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 128, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY];
```

`T_POLYGON` has:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [T_POLYGON_COORD] ON [dbo].[T_POLYGON]
(
[COORD]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 128, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY];
```

A query to find the intersection of `T_PIN` and `T_POLYGON` takes more than 45 minutes to execute:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T_PIN 
INNER JOIN T_POLYGON
    ON T_PIN.Coord.STIntersects(T_POLYGON.COORD) = 1;
```

The result is 4,438,318 rows.

How can I accelerate this query?

Comment: Have you tried using `T_POLYGON.Coord.STIntersects(T_PIN.COORD)=1'?

Comment: I would be interested to see your query plan. I work on Postgres, but have to run similar queries, but on significantly larger data sets. I have come up with a technique that gets my worst ones down to about 2 days (which unfortunately involves scripting), but I'd be interested to see your query plan first.

Comment: Multiplying the polygons in my two tables together, I have a number that is 7000 times more, in terms of the number of potential intersections, than you have in your combination, so I think in that light my two days looks quite good. However, without seeing a query plan and knowing something about the average number of points per polygon, it will be hard to come up with concrete solutions.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, check whether a spatial index is being used by looking at the query execution plan and see if there is a Clustered Index Seek (Spatial) item.

Assuming it is being used, you could try adding a secondary/simplified filter based on a bounding box with simplified polygons to check for first.  Matches against these simplified polygons could then be run through the primary filter to get the final results.

1) Add a new geography and geometry column to the [dbo].[T_POLYGON] table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_POLYGON] ADD SimplePolysGeom geometry;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_POLYGON] ADD SimplePolysGeog geography;
```

2) Create the bounding box polygons (this involves an initial conversion to geometry to take advantage of STEnvelope()):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[T_POLYGON] SET SimplePolysGeom = geometry::STGeomFromWKB(
    COORD.STAsBinary(), COORD.STSrid).STEnvelope();

UPDATE [dbo].[T_POLYGON] SET SimplePolysGeog = geography::STGeomFromWKB(
    SimplePolysGeom.STAsBinary(), SimplePolysGeom.STSrid);
```

3) Create a spatial index on the simplified geography column

4) Get the intersections against this simplified geography column, then filter again on the matching geography data types. Roughly, something like this:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT pinID, polygonID FROM T_PIN INNER JOIN T_POLYGON
    ON T_PIN.Coord.STIntersects(T_POLYGON.SimplePolysGeog ) = 1
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T_PIN 
INNER JOIN T_POLYGON
    ON T_PIN.Coord.STIntersects(T_POLYGON.COORD) = 1
    AND T_PIN.pinID IN (SELECT pinID FROM cte)
    AND T_POLYGON.polygonID IN (SELECT polygonID FROM cte)
```

**EDIT**: you can replace (1) and (2) with this computed, persisted column. credit to Paul White for the suggestion.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_POLYGON] ADD SimplePolysGeog AS  ([geography]::STGeomFromWKB([geometry]::STGeomFromWKB([COORD].[STAsBinary](),[COORD].[STSrid]).STEnvelope().STAsBinary(),(4326))) PERSISTED
```

Comment: Yeah, that is more or less what I was getting at. The issue I have found when spatially "joining" two sets of tables with a wide coverage area is that the optimizer often goes for two full table scans and loads of point in polygon tests.

Answer (score 2):

Queries like this often take a long time because of the complexity of the polygons. I've seen complex coastlines (for example) take ages to test points that are near their boundaries, having to zoom many levels to find whether a point is inside or outside.

...so you could try `.Reduce()`'ing the polygons, to see if that helps.

And for more about that function, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627410.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft docs, spatial indexes will be used with geography types on the following methods when they appear at the beginning of a comparison predicate with a `WHERE` clause:

- `STIntersects`
- `STDistance`
- `STEquals`

Only geometry types' methods (restricted list) will trigger use of spatial index in `JOIN ... ON`, so change your code to use `WHERE geog1.STIntersects(geog2) = 1` and that should improve speed.

I also recommend taking advice in [g2server's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86756/116653) and add the following for filtering and add spatial index on it

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_POLYGON] ADD SimplePolysGeog AS
     ([geography]::STGeomFromWKB([geometry]::STGeomFromWKB([COORD].[STAsBinary](),
                                                           [COORD].[STSrid])
                 .STEnvelope().STAsBinary(),(4326))) PERSISTED
```

you could then have a query *like* the following (i wrote this post quickly and have not yet tested, this is just something to try because I saw that your query and the highest posted answers use JOIN ON spatial op = 1 which will not use a spatial index):

```
SELECT   
     (SELECT p2.polygon_id
      FROM   T_Polygon p2
      WHERE  p2.coords.STIntersects(t.coords) = 1),
     t.pin_id
FROM     T_PIN t
WHERE    
     (SELECT t.coords.STIntersects(p.coords)
      FROM   T_POLYGON p
      WHERE  t.coords.STIntersects(p.SimplePolysGeog) = 1) = 1
```

FYI: The above does not work if `SimplePolysGeog` end up overlapping (as in a pin can be in two simplified geogs, just ran this on people in precincts in a state and since normal polys share boundary, the bounding boxes overlapped), so in most use cases, it will throw an error that subquery returned more than one result.

From MS Docs' [Spatial Indexes Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017):

> ### Geography Methods Supported by Spatial Indexes
>
> Under certain conditions, spatial indexes support the following set-oriented geography methods: STIntersects(),STEquals(), and STDistance(). To be supported by a spatial index, these methods must be used within the WHERE clause of a query, and they must occur within a predicate of the following general form:
>
> *geography1.method_name(geography2)comparison_operatorvalid_number*
>
> To return a non-null result, *geography1* and *geography2* must have the same [Spatial Reference Identifier (SRID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-reference-identifiers-srids?view=sql-server-2017). Otherwise, the method returns NULL.
>
> Spatial indexes support the following predicate forms:
>
> - *geography1.*[STIntersects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stintersects-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)*(geography2)= 1*
> - *geography1.*[STEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stequals-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)*(geography2)= 1*
> - *geography1.*[STDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)*(geography2) < number*
> - *geography1.*[STDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)*(geography2) <= number*
>
> ### Queries that use Spatial Indexes
>
> Spatial indexes are only supported in queries that include an indexed spatial operator in the WHERE clause. For example syntax such as:
>
> ```
> [spatial object].SpatialMethod([reference spatial object]) [ = | < ] [const literal or variable]
> ```
>
> The query optimizer understands the commutativity of spatial operations (that `@a.STIntersects(@b) = @b.STInterestcs(@a)` ). However, the spatial index will not be used if the beginning of a comparison does not contain the spatial operator (for example `WHERE 1 = spatial op` will not use the spatial index). To use the spatial index, rewrite the comparison (for example `WHERE spatial op = 1`).
>
> ...

The following query will work if `SimplePolysGeogs` overlap:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT T_PIN.PIN_ID, 
          T_POLYGON.POLYGON_ID, 
          T_POLYGON.COORD 
   FROM T_PIN 
   INNER JOIN T_POLYGON
   ON T_PIN.COORD.STIntersects(T_POLYGON.SimplePolysGeog) = 1
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T_PIN 
INNER JOIN cte
ON T_PIN_PIN_ID = cte.PIN_ID
where cte.[COORD].STIntersects(T_PIN.COORD) = 1
```

Comment: Maybe you were refering to an older version of SQL Server at the time of writing this. But the official document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017) says "To be supported by a spatial index, these methods must be used within the WHERE or JOIN ON clause of a query". So using it in the WHERE clause or JOIN ON shouldn't make a difference

Comment: @pedrambashiri yes you are correct